# How are we able to use a string to carry out this task?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

Any explanation would be helpful, for context we are using bootstrap as well so I'm not sure if this is a bootstrap feature I'm not familiar with.
This is the output
[image: output]

```
export default class Counter extends Component {
      state = {
        count: 2
      };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <span className={this.getBadgeClasses()}>{this.formatCount()}</span>
        <button className="btn btn-secondary btn-sm">Increment</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
  getBadgeClasses() {
    let classes = "badge m-2 badge-"; //this line
    classes += this.state.count === 0 ? "warning" : "primary";
    return classes;
  }

  formatCount() {
    const { count } = this.state;
    return count === 0 ? "Zero" : count;
  }
}
```

Comment: What is your problem now?

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding the line -> let classes = "badge m-2 badge-"; and how it  is able to carry out the task below it

Comment: Not react specific. Strings are strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set a string in `className` so in `getBadgeClasses` function you have to return a string.

This part is constant: `"badge m-2 badge-"`, but you want to have `"warning"` or `"primary"` in `badge-` part after `-` with some condition.

so you add it in next line:

```
classes += this.state.count === 0 ? "warning" : "primary";
```

so what return this function is `"badge m-2 badge-primary"` or `"badge m-2 badge-warning"`

Answer (score 0):

the span class base of bootstrap badge and coud be have a style base badge-primary or badge-warning (just background color different) base of the count value.

the getBadgeClasses method alwasy return a string of `badge m-2 badge-primary` or `badge m-2 badge-warning`

you can use if statement

```js
getBadgeClasses (){
 if (this.state.count === 0) {
  return 'badge m-2 badge-warning';
 } else {
  return `badge m-2 badge-primary`
 }
```

another way by using backtick and ternary operator

```js
getBadgeClasses (){
  return `badge m-2 badge-${this.state.count === 0 ? 'warning' : primary}`;
}
```

> `badge m-2 badge-` is fixed and only badge type is the one how change in your answer the use a variable to store the fixed value then the add the type base of the condition how check the count